# Как узнать цвет ячейки Excel с помощью C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, excel

Доброе время суток! Задача такова, надо вычислить в таблице Excel сколько красных ячеек, сколько зеленных ячеек, так и далее... с помощью C++ Builder.

Comment: Если кроме C++ Builder можно использовать excel, то создаёте com-объект Excel.Application (если не забыл), находите нужный шит (sheet) и исследуете ячейки.

Answer (score 2):

Затрудняюсь сказать, как узнать цвет ячейки прямо из C++ Builder. Вы можете создать макросы VBA и уже их как-нибудь использовать из приложения C++ Builder. Пример макроса:

```
Function ColorIndexOfOneCell(Cell As Range, OfText As Boolean, _
    DefaultColorIndex As Long) As Long

Dim CI As Long

Application.Volatile True
If OfText = True Then
    CI = Cell(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex
Else
    CI = Cell(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End If
If CI < 0 Then
    If IsValidColorIndex(ColorIndex:=DefaultColorIndex) = True Then
        CI = DefaultColorIndex
    Else
        CI = -1
    End If
End If

ColorIndexOfOneCell = CI

End Function
Private Function IsValidColorIndex(ColorIndex As Long) As Boolean 
    Select Case ColorIndex 
        Case 1 To 56 
            IsValidColorIndex = True 
        Case xlColorIndexAutomatic, xlColorIndexNone  
            IsValidColorIndex = True 
        Case Else 
            IsValidColorIndex = False 
    End Select 
End Function
```

Взято отсюда: [Color Functions In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx).